# spring xd pass data between jobs in composed job

Tags: spring-xd

What is the best way to pass parameters between Spring XD jobs within a composed job? Can I get parent's (composed job's) execution context to set job parameters to make them available in the next jobs?

Answer (score 0):

In short...don't.  There is no common component between the jobs within a composed job.  That feature is really intended for job orchestration.  You're better off handling any shared state between the jobs on your own.